# UIAlertViewDelegate didDismissWIthButtonIndex getting called for 1 UIAlertView, but not the other

Tags: ios, uialertview

(iOS7, xCode 5.1) I have an app that accesses the Calendar for various purposes, and I'm trying to get all of my error messaging in place.

I have 2 `UIAlertviews`. Both `UIAlertviews` show when I need them to, but I only get a call to `didDismissWIthButtonIndex` for one of them. The alertview called `_iCloudAlert` is the one that works.

If I show the `_iCloudAlert`, I get a call to `didDismissWIthButtonIndex` when a button is clicked, but when I show `_deniedAccessAlert` I get no call at all. I can't even see the outermost `NSLog`/s.

I have `<UIAlertviewDelegate>` in my `.h` file.

Code that shows the alerts, depending on Calendar access:

```
// Check the authorization status of our application for Calendar
-(void)checkEventStoreAccessForCalendar
{

    NSLog(@"Check Status");
    EKAuthorizationStatus status = [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];

    switch (status)
    {
            // Update our UI if the user has granted access to their Calendar
        case EKAuthorizationStatusAuthorized: [self accessGrantedForCalendar];
            NSLog(@"Already granted");
            break;
            // Prompt the user for access to Calendar if there is no definitive answer
        case EKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined: [self requestCalendarAccess];
            break;
            // Display a message if the user has denied or restricted access to Calendar
        case EKAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        case EKAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
        {
            NSLog(@"already denied");
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showDeniedAccessAlert) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Both alert view methods:

```
- (void)informUserAboutCloud {

    _iCloudAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Important!"
                          message: @"If you have an iCloud account.....blah, blah, blah..."
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [_iCloudAlert show];

}

- (void)showDeniedAccessAlert {

    NSLog(@"Show Denied Access Alert");

    _deniedAccessAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Attention!"
                          message: @"It looks like you've blocked access to Calendar data... Blah, Blah, Blah..."
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [_deniedAccessAlert show];

}
```

And here is the code used to take action on the button clicks:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    NSLog(@"button index: %i", buttonIndex); //only logs when _iCloudAlert is shown
    NSLog(@"alertview: %@", alert); //only logs when _iCloudAlert is shown

    if (_iCloudAlert) {

        [self checkEventStoreAccessForCalendar];
        NSLog(@"check for calendar access from dismissed icloud alert...");

    } 

    if (_deniedAccessAlert) {

        NSLog(@"dismissed denied access..."); //never logged
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion - instead of using ivars for each alert view, have no ivars. Instead, assign each alert its own tag value. Then in the delegate method you can check the `tag` property of the `alert` parameter.

Comment: so `if(alert.tag == 1)`, etc? What would be the main benefit of doing it that way vs ivars?

Comment: It's really a personal choice. I prefer to simply define a new constant for each alert tag I might have in one class instead of adding a new ivar. It also allows you to use a `switch` statement on the alert's tag to handle each one if needed. Of course with ivars you can setup a set of `if-else` statements.

Comment: Yeah, it said I had to wait 12 mins.... you guys answered in about 15 seconds. I've never had to wait before. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd UIAlertView has its delegate set to nil. Change that, and it will work!

Comment: You beat me by 2 seconds. :)

Comment: LOL :) Thank you for removing your answer, you didn't have to do that!